# Int lists in functions

Tags: list, ocaml

Does this function take two int lists "x and y" and return an int list of y-x?

```
let rec fun4 (l: int list) :int list =
  begin match l with | [] -> []
  | [_] -> []
  | x::y::rest -> (y-x)::(fun4 (y::rest)) 
end
```

Comment: no, it takes a single list of integers, you may want to try running it to see what it does. The x::y::rest syntax in the match clause binds successive elements in a list to x and y variables

Answer (score 1):

A list is defined as a recursive type:

```ml
type 'a list = 
  | [] of 'a list (* the empty case *)
  | ( :: ) of 'a * 'a list
```

So you basically have two constructors: `[]` which is the empty list, and `x :: other_list` which is a list with `x` as head and `other_list` as tail. The use of these constructors makes it easy to define a list: `[0; 1; 2; 3]` is exactly the same of `0 :: 1 :: 2 :: 3` and of `(::) (0, (::) (1, (::) (2, (::) (3, []))))` (which is not very pleasant to read).

Recursive algebraic types, here we have the conjunction of sums (`[]` and `(::)`) and products (`('a * 'a list)`), combined with pattern matching make it possible to describe all sorts of common data structures, as well as their functions for consuming, modifying etc.

In your example, you use pattern matching to deconstruct the list:

```ml
let rec fun4 my_list = 
  match my_list with 

  (* if my list is empty, I can't process the function so 
     I return the empty list *)
  | [] -> [] 

  (* if my list my list has only one element, I can't process the function
     so, like in the previouse case, I return the empty list *)
  | [ _ ] -> []

  (* Here is the last case of the function, If I almost have two elements in the 
     list. Remember that empty list is also a list ! *)
  | x :: y :: rest -> (y - x) :: (fun4 (y :: rest))
```

As you can see, Recursives Algebraic data types coupled with pattern matching are a powerful for describing data structures (like list but also many others) and for writing function that use those data structures.

Comment: Suggested: `let[@tail_mod_cons] rec fun4 = function [] | [_] -> [] | x::(y::_ as tl) -> (y - x) :: fun4 tl`